# Can I popagate this soil-suffocated Dracaena node? Is it dead?

Tags: houseplants, dracaena

While transplanting my Dracaena into a larger pot. I noticed what looked like a stick or root laying in the soil that had shook loose. After looking closer its a underdeveloped nodeI think. Its about 5 inches long. It's not dried out, and the soil it was in is still good.[image] It's strange... I'm wondering if this is still alive? And if so, what can I do to get it going? Help out if you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because it is white it looks alive; they are tough. The first ( and only ) one I bought was a 3 inch length dry stem ; but I forget if I rooted it in soil or water . I think potting mix would be best but not critical. 60 years later I have descendents.